# Populate href with link from input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use an input to allow the end user to change the `href` of an a element using JavaScript, and I can't seem to get things working quite right.

Here's what I have so far...

```
<input type="text" id="feed" />
<a id="display" href="">#</a>
```

```
$('#feed').keyup(function () {
var temp = "";
temp = $('#feed').text.val();
  $('#display').href = temp;
});
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: temp = $('#feed').val();

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `.text` that will throws error in console. To get the value you just need to use **[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** method on jQuery object.

Since `$('#display')` returns a jQuery object you need to use **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** to update an attribute (or use **[`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop)** and update `href` property) or you need to get dom object by `$('#display')[0]` and update `href` property.

```
$('#feed').keyup(function () {
    var temp = $('#feed').val();
    $('#display').attr('href', temp);
});
```

Comment: Also, you could use `$('#display').attr('href', temp)` to assign the href if you were so inclined.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the $ means you're using jQuery.

```
$('#feed').keyup(function () {
var temp = "";
temp = $('#feed').val();
  $('#display').attr('href', temp);
});
```

Comment: He has also tagged it as jquery